# Replace placeholder text in Docs with a block of text in a Sheet cell as a bulleted list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, replace, google-docs

I have created a template Google Doc with data that needs to be replaced with real data from a Google Sheet. In most cases everything works, but there are some instances where I want to be able to have a block of text from a cell in the sheet to be formatted as a bullet list in the doc.

Since the text being replaced, like for instance "{whatYouDoResponsibilities}", is formatted as a bulleted list in the template doc it just ends up as one bullet point with the entire content of the cell, instead of being several bulleted points.

So if the contents of the cell I want to replace "{whatYouDoResponsibilities}" looks like this:

Blablabla
Blablabla
Blablabla

It ends up looking like this in the doc:

- Blablabla
  Blablabla
  Blablabla

Instead of this, as I want it to:

- Blablabla
- Blablabla
- Blablabla

Is there any way to solve this?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Here is the code:

```
function createBulkDocs() {

  const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("");
  const currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Job Ad Generator");
  
  var file_iterator = tempFolder.getFiles();
  
  while (file_iterator.hasNext()) {
    var file = file_iterator.next();
    Logger.log('Deleting file "%s"',
                 file.getName());
 
    Drive.Files.remove(file.getId())
  }

  const data = currentSheet.getRange(2, 1,currentSheet.getLastRow()-1,14).getDisplayValues();
  
  let errors =[];
  
  data.forEach(row => {
      
  var gradeStatus = row[13];             
        if(gradeStatus == ""){ }
  else {
    createDocs(row[3], row[4], row[4], row[7], row[8],row[9] + row[8], row[3] + " " + "Grade" + " " + row[6], row[11], row[12], docFile, tempFolder, row[13]); 
  }
  
  });
  
}

function createDocs(jobTitle, craftNameUpp, craftName, whoYouWorkWith, whatYouDoSummary,whatYouDoResponsibilities, docName, whoYouAreSummary,whoYouAreSpecifics, docFile, tempFolder, seniority) {
  
  const tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(tempFolder);
  const tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId())
  const body = tempDocFile.getBody();

  body.replaceText("{JOBTITLE}", jobTitle);
  body.replaceText("{CRAFTNAME}", craftNameUpp);
  body.replaceText("{craftname}", craftName);
  body.replaceText("{whoYouWorkWith}", whoYouWorkWith);
  body.replaceText("{whatYouDoSummary}", whatYouDoSummary);
  body.replaceText("{whatYouDoResponsibilities}", whatYouDoResponsibilities);
  body.replaceText("{whoYouAreSummary}", whoYouAreSummary);
  body.replaceText("{whoYouAreSpecifics}", whoYouAreSpecifics);
  body.replaceText("{seniority}", seniority);
  
  tempDocFile.setName(docName);
  tempDocFile.saveAndClose();
 
}
```

Comment: I tried an example and I don't see the problem.  I wonder if you have any additional white space like carriage returns or line feeds in your data.  You might want trim white space off of your data.

Comment: Share some of your raw data as a csv and I'll look at it. Note: don't bother providing me with a link to a spreadsheet because I won't use it.

Comment: Yeah, I use ALT + ENTER to separate lines in the text in the cell.

Comment: Yes well that's the problem.

Comment: An example of the data:

Role,What you do - summary,What you do - responsibilties,What you do - tasks
HeadOf,,"Do X

Do Y",

Comment: Each ListItem is a separate child.

Comment: @Cooper How could I otherwise do it?

Comment: Split on carriage returns and load each listitem separately

Comment: Can I do that in the script or do I have to do it in the sheet?

Comment: I'd do it in a script.

Comment: I would need to see and image of your template

Comment: Here you go: https://imgur.com/a/EWg6j4Y

Comment: What I would do is just build document in my script and not mess with the template at all.   It seems like a pretty simple template so I don't think it would difficult to do.

Comment: Hi ! Could you please share a link to your Spreadhsheet *with no sensitive data* so that it is easier for me to reasearch this and provide an appropiate and accurate solution? Many thanks ! :D